# Bypass Postfix 'reject_unknown_client_hostname' for authenticated SMTP clients

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server, authentication

In my postfix configuration, I've switched on `smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unknown_client_hostname` as an anti-spam measure.

However, sometimes I fall foul of this myself when I make an authenticated SMTP connection to the server from remote hosts that don't have reverse DNS.  My attempt to send an email gets rejected.

Is there any way to ignore `smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unknown_client_hostname` in the case of an authenticated client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not restrict authenticated clients by the reject_unknown_client_hostname restrictions you can simply place the permit_sasl_authenticated directive before it. See http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#permit_sasl_authenticated

Example:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unknown_client_hostname
```

Maybe you want to also permit "mynetworks".

Tip: in addition you can also use the reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname and reject_unknown_helo_hostname restriction within the smtpd_helo_restrictions to minimize spam. But same as above, place permit_sasl_authenticated before it to not restrict your authenticated clients.

Example:

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to permit authenticated clients, for instance:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unknown_client_hostname,
        #...the rest of them,
        permit
```